# How to ignore the windows error prompt on program execution?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a program running on Windows cmd and when the program throws an error it keeps waiting for user input to either ignore/continue or cancel, but i have this batch file wich restarts the program automatically on error but since it keeps waiting for user input i have to go there and press a button

```
:unturned

echo (%time%) Unturned started.

cd masterserver
cd VisualStudio
cd Debug
masterserver.exe  

@echo All done!
@echo Masterserver listening on port: 23466

echo (%time%) WARNING: Unturned closed or crashed, restarting. >>c:\crashlog.txt

ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 >nul

goto unturned
```

How to make it ignore the error and continue automatically?

Here is an image of the prompt:

[image]

Comment: Since there is no such prompt in the script itself, it has to be masterserver itself doing the prompt before exiting. Does it have a command-line parameter to disable the prompt?

Comment: I download it from here http://unity3d.com/master-server and compile with visual studio then i just start the exe with this batch, don't know about command-line parameter

Answer (score 1):

That popup message is displayed when an assertion failure occurs in `masterserver.exe`.  The failure indicates a code bug, as it is testing a condition at compile-time that is expected to always be true at run-time, but the condition was actually false instead.

In this case, the error happened in  `CCRakNetUDT::OnAck()` in `ccraknetudt.cpp` on line 528. That line is calling `RakAssert(rtt < 10000000);`, where `rtt` is an input parameter to `OnAck()`.  The assertion is that the value of `rtt` should always be less than `10000000`, but it was actually not.

```
void CCRakNetUDT::OnAck(CCTimeType curTime, CCTimeType rtt, bool hasBAndAS, BytesPerMicrosecond _B, BytesPerMicrosecond _AS, double totalUserDataBytesAcked, bool isContinuousSend, DatagramSequenceNumberType sequenceNumber )
{
#if CC_TIME_TYPE_BYTES==4
    RakAssert(rtt < 10000);
#else
    RakAssert(rtt < 10000000); // <-- line 528
#endif
```

When you compile a debug build of `masterserver.exe` for platforms other than Xbox, `RakAssert()` maps to [`assert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx), otherwise it is a no-op:

RakAssert.h

```
#include <assert.h>
#include "RakNetDefines.h"
```

RakNetDefines.h

```
#ifndef RakAssert
#if defined(_XBOX) || defined(X360)
                    
#else
#if defined(_DEBUG)
#define RakAssert(x) assert(x);
#else
#define RakAssert(x) 
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

Per the [`assert()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx):

> Evaluates an expression and, when the result is false, **prints a diagnostic message and aborts the program**.
>
> ...
>
> The assert macro is typically used to identify logic errors during program development. Use it to stop program execution when unexpected conditions occur by implementing the expression argument to evaluate to false only when the program is operating incorrectly. **Assertion checks can be turned off at compile time by defining the macro `NDEBUG`. You can turn off the assert macro without modifying your source files by using a `/DNDEBUG` command-line option. You can turn off the assert macro in your source code by using a `#define NDEBUG` directive before `<assert.h>` is included**.
>
> The assert macro prints a diagnostic message when expression evaluates to false (0) **and calls `abort` to terminate program execution**. No action is taken if expression is true (nonzero). The diagnostic message includes the failed expression, the name of the source file and line number where the assertion failed.
>
> ...
>
> The destination of the diagnostic message depends on the type of application that called the routine. Console applications always receive the message through `stderr`. **In a Windows-based application, `assert` calls the Windows `MessageBox` function to create a message box to display the message along with an `OK` button. When the user clicks `OK`, the program aborts immediately**.
>
> **When the application is linked with a debug version of the run-time libraries, `assert` creates a message box with three buttons: `Abort`, `Retry`, and `Ignore`**. If the user clicks `Abort`, the program aborts immediately. If the user clicks `Retry`, the debugger is called and the user can debug the program if just-in-time (JIT) debugging is enabled. If the user clicks `Ignore`, `assert` continues with its normal execution: creating the message box with the `OK` button. Note that clicking `Ignore` when an error condition exists can result in undefined behavior.
>
> ...
>
> The `assert` macro is enabled in both the release and debug versions of the C run-time libraries when `NDEBUG` is not defined. **When `NDEBUG` is defined, the macro is available but does not evaluate its argument and has no effect**. When it is enabled, the `assert` macro calls `_wassert` for its implementation. Other assertion macros, `_ASSERT`, `_ASSERTE` and `_ASSERT_EXPR`, are also available, but they only evaluate the expressions passed to them when the `_DEBUG` macro has been defined and when they are in code linked with the debug version of the C run-time libraries.

So, if you want to disable this particular popup error, you need to either:

1. find the root cause of the error and fix it (or contact the Unity author to fix it), since it is a code bug.
2. compile `masterserver.exe` for release instead of debug, so `RakAssert()` is a no-op.
3. define `NDEBUG` in the source code, in the project solution, or via the compiler's `/D` switch on the command-line, so `assert()` is a no-op.

Just know that disabling the assertion will risk the app crashing or behaving incorrectly if the error happens again.

Comment: wow, thank you. I have already posted on unity forum but as i've seen the code is from raknet itself not unity and raknet fórum seems to be disabled. Since me fixing the code is not an option i think i'll need to live with the error for the time, i'm trying the /d command line i'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Updating in case someone has this problem:
I compiled it in Release mode just like Remy said and the problem has gone away completely, the application now runs properly without any errors.